# Como parar a execução da função $.map?

Tags: jquery

Como faço para parar a execução da função `$.map` quando uma condição do *`if`* for verdadeiro?

Com `for` eu usuaria um `break` assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    if (true)
        break;
}
```

E na função `$.map` do Jquery, como seria?

Comment: Qual é o objetivo? Talvez `map` não seja a função adequada, porque ela é feita para transformar *todos* os valores da array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar sua própria função de mapeamento se a do jQuery não lhe resolve.

```
var stoppableMap = function (inputArray, mainFunction, haltFunction) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (haltFunction(result, inputArray[i], i) === false) {
            break;
        }
        result.push(mainFunction(inputArray[i], i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

O que acontece aqui é o seguinte: você chama a função acima passando um vetor como entrada e uma função que recebe índice e elemento, de forma semelhante ao que faria com a função `$.map.`.

Para cada elemento do vetor, a função passada como o parâmetro `mainFunction` será executada uma vez. o primeiro parâmetro que ela recebe é elemento atual, e o segundo parâmetro é o índice do elemento atual.

A diferença está na função passada como o terceiro parâmetro, `haltFunction`. Ela também é executada para cada elemento do vetor original, mas antes da `mainFunction`. Ela recebe três parâmetros: o vetor resultante do mapeamento até o momento, o elemento atual e o índice do elemento atual. Se ela retornar `false` (explícito - `""`, `0`, `null` e `undefined` não servem), o laço da função de mapeamento é interrompido. CQD.

Você pode modificar a função a vontade: fazer a função de parada executar depois e não antes da função principal, passar um parâmetro a mais para ter mais contexto ou o que mais sua lógica precisar.

Note que essa função é bem mais simples do que a `$.map`. Ela não itera sobre objetos e nem achata vetores a cada rodada da função principal que você passa. Você pode implementar esses detalhes se necessário.

Exemplo de uso, que para quando encontra um elemento de valor `3`:

```
stoppableMap([1, 2, 3, 4, "a Maria é um barato"],
        function (elem) {
            return "elemento de valor " + elem;
        },
        function (accumulate, elem) {
            if (elem == 3) return false;
        });
```

Boa sorte ;)

Answer (score 3):

Você não pode "quebrar" a execução da função map. 
Recomendo dar uma olhada na função [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Comment: o $each eu consigo para a execução?

Comment: Sim, retornando `false` da função passada a ele. Mas seria legal esclarecer melhor o seu objetivo com a pergunta, talvez exista alguma solução melhor. E `for` comum você também pode usar e dar `break`, exatamente como em C#.

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível interromper o **fluxo** de [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) em si pois seu propósito é ser aplicado em todos os elementos do array dado. Mas é possível sim fazer seu *callback* ignore determinados valores da iteração, não se aplicando neles de acordo com alguma condição.

Rotinas de *mapping* na grande maioria das vezes visam, como o próprio nome sugere, mapear os elementos de um array de alguma coisa para alguma outra coisa. Caso algum elemento não deva ser mapeado, basta retornar o próprio elemento:

```js
var arr = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ];
 
arr = jQuery.map( arr, function( n, i ) {
  if ( i == 2 ) { return n; }
  return ( n.toUpperCase() );
});

console.log( arr );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Observando o console veremos que todos os elementos do array passado foram mapeados para letras maiúsculas, exceto o terceiro índice que foi mantido inalterado.

É possível também, apesar de errado, usar [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map) como alternativa a [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each), executando alguma coisa para cada elemento do array de entrada sem, de fato, transformá-lo em nada.

Para esses casos, ao invés de retornar o valor corrente, um `return false` permite "pular" a iteração corrente quando alguma condição se satisfizer.

```js
$.map( [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ], function( val, i ) {
  
    if( i > 2 ) return false;
    
    alert( val );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Nesse exemplo eu verifico o índice corrente da iteração. Se for maior que 2 eu encerro a iteração e, consequentemente, a entrada **four** não é mostrada no alert().

Comment: Obrigado pelos dois pés no peito sem um comentário sequer. Até parece que se enganar é proibido...

Comment: Passando por aqui e vi seu comentario, agradeço pela resposta. Desculpe ;)